# Finding newest date from JSON in python

Tags: python, datetime

I would like to find the trip with the newest departure date and time (the furtherest away) from a JSON.

```
[
  {
    "DEPARTURE PORT": "Ischia",
    "ARRIVAL PORT": "Napoli Molo Beverello",
    "DEPARTURE DATE": "2019-02-20",
    "DEPARTURE TIME": "06:30",
    "ARRIVAL DATE": "2019-02-18",
    "ARRIVAL TIME": "07:20",
    "DURATION": "00:50:00"
  },
  {
    "DEPARTURE PORT": "Forio",
    "ARRIVAL PORT": "Napoli Molo Beverello",
    "DEPARTURE DATE": "2019-02-16",
    "DEPARTURE TIME": "06:45",
    "ARRIVAL DATE": "2019-02-16",
    "ARRIVAL TIME": "08:05",
    "DURATION": "01:20:00"
  },
  {
    "DEPARTURE PORT": "Napoli Molo Beverello",
    "ARRIVAL PORT": "Ischia",
    "DEPARTURE DATE": "2019-02-18",
    "DEPARTURE TIME": "07:05",
    "ARRIVAL DATE": "2019-02-18",
    "ARRIVAL TIME": "08:25",
    "DURATION": "01:20:00"
  }
]
```

I've tried the following but is there a better way of doing it?

```
#Read the JSON
with open('livedepartures/alilauro.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    alilauro_data = json.loads(data_file.read())

 newest_alilauro_date = max(
       datetime.strptime( d + " " + t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" ) 
       for d, t in zip( alilauro_data["DEPARTURE DATE"],  alilauro_data["DEPARTURE TIME"])
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Pandas is great for any sort of data thing like this

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_json("sample.json")
data['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data["DEPARTURE DATE"] + ' ' + data["DEPARTURE TIME"])
print(data['timestamp'].max())
```

Will give you

```
2019-02-20 06:30:00
```

Comment: Great answer! But I think you would need to handle departures in the same day and hence also account for a max() in time.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. The nice thing about ISO format is that you can actually perform string sorting (provided you have dates or UTC timestamps - with timezone `"Z"`).

```
newest_alilauro_trip = max(
  alilauro_data,
  key=lambda item: item["DEPARTURE DATE"] + item["DEPARTURE TIME"]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you've decoded this, you only need `max`. First, define a function to extract the departure date and time from a dict. `operator.itemgetter` makes this easy.

```
from operator import itemgetter

# get_departure({..., "DEPARTURE DATE": "2019-02-20",  "DEPARTURE TIME": "06:30", ...})
#   == ("2019-02-20", "06:30")
get_departure = itemgetter("DEPARTURE DATE", "DEPARTURE TIME")
```

Now, just use this as the key function for determining what the "size" of a `dict` is when computing the largest `dict`.

```
with open('livedepartures/alilauro.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    alilauro_data = json.loads(data_file.read())

newest_alilauro = max(alilauro_data, key=get_departure)
```

This will give you the `dict` with the latest departure. If all you want is the departure itself, you can pass a list of tuples to `max` instead of using `key`. Instead of computing the largest `dict`, we're computing the largest tuple.

```
 newest_departure = max(map(get_departure, alilauro_data))
```

Each date and time is already formatted so that their lexicographic ordering is the same as their chronological ordering.

Comment: or you can pass the sorting key to `max`

Comment: That's what I did in the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to use external libraries, I would look into [Maya](https://github.com/kennethreitz/maya). With this library you can easily parse all the departure dates and times in your JSON file and find the one with the shortest distance to `maya.now()`, assuming that's what you're going for with 'newest departure date and time'.

Unfortunately if you're not guaranteeed any kind of ordering in the JSON source file, the only way I can see of doing this is parsing all of them and checking which one is newest. At least with Maya it will be easier to deal with datetimes, though :)

Answer (score 0):

You have no reason to zip here because the json will yield a list of dictionaries. You can simply do:

```
#Read the JSON
with open('livedepartures/alilauro.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
    alilauro_data = json.loads(data_file.read())

newest_alilauro_date = max((datetime.datetime.strptime(it["DEPARTURE DATE"]+it["DEPARTURE TIME"],
                "%Y-%m-%d%H:%M") for it in alilauro_data))
```